# connect react redux HOC got error of `Cannot call a class as a function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

What's wrong with my HOC below? I got error of cannot call a class as function?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPRO.png

My HOC

```
const CheckPermission = (Component) => { 
    return class App extends Component { 
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchUsers().then(resp => {
                this.setState({user: true, loading: false});
            })
        } 
        render() { 
           const { user, loading } = this.props

           loading && <div>Loading...</div>

           !user && <Redirect to="/dashboard" />

           return <Component {...this.props} />
        }
    } 
}


export default connect(state=>state.global, {fetchUsers})(CheckPermission)
```

This is how I import and user CheckPermission:

`<Route exact path='/dashboard' component={CheckPermission(Dashboard)} />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't wrap `checkPermissions` with a `connect` because it is also a HOC.
Instead you have to compose them.

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
```

...

```
export default compose(
  connect(state=>state.global, {fetchUsers}),  
  CheckPermission
);
```

Comment: same error I still got, this is my full file https://pastebin.com/HRdthN80

Comment: at line 7 why you are adding curly braces around `Component`

Comment: I edited my code snippet to reorder the arguments passed to compose

Comment: I removed the curly braces and now it worked, does it matter the order of compose arguments ?

Comment: yes, because `compose` passes the result of the second function to the first, and in `checkPermission` you need the props passed by connect.

Comment: but I tried to changed the order, it doesn't work, I put CheckPermission as second arg, it worked, can you verify that again? your previous solution worked.

Comment: where does `appliedAd` come?

Comment: What about if I am not using redux??